# Python ValueError Exception not being caught properly

Tags: python, exception, valueerror

`item`is a **python dictionary**

```
print item.get('body')
```

gives the following output in some cases:

> "1211V1"

however, *item.get('body')* mostly has a unicode string of the format:

> u'{"points_token_id":"327727a0-3909-4132-8fa2-ee45146add1e"}'

I needed to convert the above unicode string to a python dictionary. So I am doing this:

```
try:
    body_dic = json.loads(item.get('body'))
    body_string = ""

    for body_item in body_dic.keys():
        body_string += body_item + ": {'required': True, 'type': 'resource', 'value': " + str(body_dic.get('body_item')) + "\n\t\t\t\t"

except Exception as e:
    print "futt gayaa"
    print type(e).__name__
    print e.args
    body_string = item.get('body')
```

and then a bunch of code after this. So in the above the moment *item.get('body')* comes out to be *"1211V1"* a **ValueError Exception** should be raised and the execution flow should get into the *except* block. Am I right ?

It does not get raised however and the execution flow continues to go onto the next line which is :

```
for body_item in body_dic.keys():
```

and then the following exception gets raised:

> AttributeError
>   ("'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'",)

which I get to know if I change the *except* block in the above to catch a generic exception as :

```
except Exception as e:
    print "futt gayaa"
    print type(e).__name__
    print e.args
    body_string = item.get('body')
```

Please help me understand this. In my opinion the moment the first exception gets raised (which in our case should be the **ValueError Exception**) the control flow should go into the catch block. Why does it go to the next line of code and then when the **Attribute Exception** gets raised does it get caught.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error.

Comment: you probably serialized a string, not a dict. So `json.loads` returns a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that, as you wrote

```
print item.get("body")
```

returns literally

```
"1211V1"
```

then the quotation marks are part of the string itself.

So you effectively calling

```
json.loads('"1211V1"')
```

where you are loading a JSON string literal--perfectly valid.  Then, of course, you get an `AttributeError` for trying to call `.keys()` on a `unicode` object.

If you're using `print` to debug a problem it might mislead you in this way--you're better off often, if you really want to be sure what the object is that you're having trouble with, writing `print(repr(obj))`.  In this case that would tell you that `item.get("body")` is `u'"1211V1"'`.

Comment: I'm also a bit disturbed that you seem to be trying to build a JSON string of some kind by hand with string concatenation.  I won't ask why, but it's a good bet you're going down the wrong path there without a great reason...

Comment: Thanks @Iguananaut. Made perfect sense. As of the approach, as to why am I trying to build a JSON string of some kind by hand, long story short, there is a legacy tool that expects data in a certain format. We need to extend the code. (Please don't ask why is refactoring not an option right now :D ) Hence all this circus around with strings and JSON.

Comment: @qre0ct you can still build it with the `json` module and not adding `str`s, [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps)

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you have a sequence of dicts, whose attribute body is a JSON string. It may either be:

```
"1211V1"
```

or:

```
{
    "points_token_id":"327727a0-3909-4132-8fa2-ee45146add1e"
}
```

This is, a JSON string or a JSON object. By `json.loads()`ing this string you are always getting a valid Python value, either a Python `str` or a Python `dict`, respectively. What you want to do is detect if its one or another:

```
json_body = json.loads(item['body'])
if type(json_body) is dict:
    for key, value in json_body.items():
        json_body[key] = {'required': True, 'type': 'resource', 'value': value}
    body_string = json.dumps(json_body)
else:
    pass # Handle the "1211V1"
```